# Transform javascript array of object in object with keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here what I have :

```
const datas = [
  {id: '/chiens', content: ['waf1','waf2']},
  {id: '/chats', content: ['miaou1','miaou2']},
  {id: '/oiseaux', content: ['cui1','cui2']}
]
```

Here what I want :

```
const datasFiltered = {
   chiens : ['waf1','waf2'],
   chats : ['miaou1','miaou2'],
   oiseaux : ['cui1','cui2']
}
```

How I can do that ? With `reduce` maybe ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post a code snippet showing an attempt from you.

Comment: You're right, I would have to. I had tried in 2 steps, with reduce...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code.

```js
const datas = [
  { id: "/chiens", content: ["waf1", "waf2"] },
  { id: "/chats", content: ["miaou1", "miaou2"] },
  { id: "/oiseaux", content: ["cui1", "cui2"] }
];

const updated = datas.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({
    ...acc,
    [curr.id.split("/")[1]]: curr.content,
    // alternatively
    // [curr.id.slice(1)]: curr.content
  }),
  {}
);

console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` for creating the desired result.

```js
const datas = [{id: '/chiens', content: ['waf1','waf2']},{id: '/chats', content: ['miaou1','miaou2']},{id: '/oiseaux', content: ['cui1','cui2']}],
      datasFiltered = datas.reduce((a, {id: [_, ...key], content}) => Object.assign(a, {[key.join("")]: content}), Object.create(null));

console.log(datasFiltered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should construct new object based on your data array, something like

```
    let newObj = {};    
    datas.foreach(item => {
    newObj[item['id']] = item['content'];  
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the array to an array of entries [key, value], and convert to an object with `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const datas = [
  { id: "/chiens", content: ["waf1", "waf2"] },
  { id: "/chats", content: ["miaou1", "miaou2"] },
  { id: "/oiseaux", content: ["cui1", "cui2"] }
];

const result = Object.fromEntries(datas.map(({ id, content }) => [
  id.replace('/', ''),
  content
]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach too to achieve this.

```js
const datas = [
  {id: '/chiens', content: ['waf1','waf2']},
  {id: '/chats', content: ['miaou1','miaou2']},
  {id: '/oiseaux', content: ['cui1','cui2']}
]

const result = {};
datas.forEach((el) => {
  const key = el.id.substring(1,(el.id.length));
  result[key] = el.content;
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below

```
[
    { id: '/chiens', content: ['waf1', 'waf2'] },
    { id: '/chats', content: ['miaou1', 'miaou2'] },
    { id: '/oiseaux', content: ['cui1', 'cui2'] },
].reduce((acc, ele) => {
    const newContent = (acc[ele.id.replace('/', '')] = ele.content);
    return { ...acc, newContent };
}, {});
```